# Image on "Page Not Found"-page was misaligned

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, 404-not-found

[I saw a report in a chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/19956290#19956290), that "404 error page on Server Fault was broken (the image isn't aligned correctly)".

[image: SF broken 404]

Looks like Super User also has this "issue".

[image: SU broken 404]

But Stack Overflow seems fine here.

[image: SO good 404]

By looking from Chrome developer tools, looks like *some properties* were missing.

[image: Comparison SF and SO]

This behavior is tested from Firefox,Chrome and Opera on Windows 7.

**Is it intended design?**

Comment: I got the same error on Chrome, with Windows 8. What are you using?

Comment: using Firefox,Chrome and Opera on Windows 7.

Comment: I was about to advise you to put that into the question, but I see you've already done that, and then some :) ....this is a pretty good bug report; well done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Confirmed, the width is missing on the 404 page.  This will be fixed in the next build.