# Error submitting question when it contains bare question URL with big question ID

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown, asking-questions

When crafting [this question about "404-page"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/248289/260672), I've tried give an example of not-found-page by using *big question ID*, for example **this bare URL** `https://serverfault.com/questions/5321111111`. When I submit the question, the submit button reported an error with message **"An error occurred submitting the question."** Instead telling me about what's wrong with my question, the page tells me nothing.

Looking through HTTP status code, I see "302 Found" status-code followed by "500 Internal Server Error" like below.

[image: HTTP status code]

- This error wasn't shown when I put bare URL pointing to existed question https://serverfault.com/questions/5321
- The error wasn't shown when I put bare URL pointing to removed question (but has question ID below 5321111111) https://serverfault.com/questions/532342 ,
- This error also wasn't shown when I wrap the put the URL into [non-bare URL like this](https://serverfault.com/questions/5321111111).

Looks like [Markdown parser for bare-URL](https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help#bare-urls) was misbehaving in this case.

Why did meta.SE dislike my bare URL?

Comment: My guess: it tried to fetch the title of question, and did not handle the failure properly. Does this happen for all non-existent question numbers, or just for very long ones?

Comment: Hi, I've tried to put the example of removed links by editing my question. It seems the system gladly accept it.

Comment: @famous hey, at least they are not trying to handle the success ;).

Comment: @FamousBlueRaincoat Hmm, I'm curious why they need to fetch the title of the links?

Comment: To have links with informative titles instead of bare URL, I suppose.

Comment: all the id's are 32-bit ints, and will be 32-bit until we start getting close to the Int32.MaxValue on a site (presumably [so])

Comment: @m0sa At least the system can tell the user about this 'error'. At first, I'm just puzzled why I can't submit [the question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/248289/260672). There are no error message mentioned. After several try and error, finally I can submit it after 'clean' the links.

Comment: the error is caused by an exception when parsing the big number as an 32-bit int. Best case I can do is make it consistent with the markdown preview so it shows up as a raw URL link.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, the maximum ID seems to be "2147483647", after which you can't submit the post (answer or question equally) with a bare link, which would resolve into the post title. Apparently Stack Exchange isn't using [64-bits systems](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10255765/792066) (oh, the horror!) or there's an integer overflow somewhere.

Answer (score 4):

After build rev `2015.2.12.3070` on meta, `2015.2.12.2293` on sites, you will get a bare URL link, even for a question/post URL with an ill-formatted id.

Comment: `Int32.TryParse` instead of `Int32.Parse?`? ;)

Comment: guilty as charged